# Error: undefined method `contact' for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, hobo

I have a ruby/rails/hobo system that someone wrote a couple years ago, that I need to port to the latest version of ruby/rails/hobo. It seems that ruby doesn't care about backward compatibility, so code that used to work in the old app doesn't work anymore:

In the observation.rb model file, the old app has this:

```
belongs_to :survey
has_one :site, :through => :survey

def create_permitted?
  acting_user == self.survey.contact or acting_user.administrator?
end
```

survey.rb model file has this:

```
belongs_to :contact, :class_name => 'User', :creator => true
```

Unfortunately the code in observation.rb doesn't work under the new ruby/rails/hobo, and it gives me the error:

```
NoMethodError in Observations#index

Showing controller: observations; dryml-tag: index-page where line #1 raised:

undefined method `contact' for nil:NilClass
Extracted source (around line #1):

0
Rails.root: /home/simon/ruby/frogwatch2

Application Trace | Framework Trace | Full Trace
app/models/observation.rb:48:in `create_permitted?'
```

How should the "create_permitted" method be changed? I'm finding that the documentation for ruby/rails/hobo is pretty atrocious (which is fair enough as it is free software). Also I don't even know how to begin searching for this on google (i've been trying for days).

Please help! :)

Comment: Hey Simon, if you have been looking for docs for days (as you state), you might have stumbled upon A) [Rails API Docs](http://api.rubyonrails.org/), B) [the Rails guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/) and C) [Ruby Core Docs](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/). If not, you know them now. I consider these docs great, and so incredibly detailed that they are far from being 'atrocious'.

Comment: Hey Thomas, thanks so much for the links. I just want to apologize to all you ruby/rails folks for me taking a stab at ruby docs. :) I was really frustrated. My main issue with ruby docs was trying to find any documentation on "sigils".. like the ":" character and the "?" character.. how does one even begin to search for that on google? Anyway, I used "acting_user == (survey && survey.contact)" because it looked like the easiest option.. Thanks everyone for all your kind help!!!

Comment: I changed it to "survey && (acting_user == survey.contact)" cos it's easier for me to understand that way..

Comment: Simon, have you seen the Hobo documentation at cookbook.hobocentral.net?  We put a lot of work into that, so I hope you find it helpful.   Of course, it's designed to be used in conjunction with Ruby & Rails documentation.  If you have problems in the future, I would suggest also posting to the hobousers mailing list.  There's a friendly group there who can help you out with Hobo related problems, there aren't many of us hoboists who hang out here on StackOverflow.

Answer (score 2):

Apart from differing views on the docs around Rails, you are calling `contact` on a survey which does not exist in this case, resulting in a call `nil.contact`.

An alternative would be to check for the presence of the survey before calling `contact`, e.g in such a way.

```
def create_permitted?
  acting_user == (survey && survey.contact) or acting_user.administrator?
end
```

Comment: On a relationship, `present?` is usually redundant. Either it's there or it's not there.

Comment: How would you check for survey not being nil before calling contact on it?

Comment: Unless there's a possibility of it being literally `false`, which for an association is never the case, you can just use standard boolean logic: `acting_user == survey && survey.contact` The `present?` method is useful for distinguishing things that are technically defined but not sufficiently non-empty, like a blank string, an empty hash or array. It's very heavy-handed for a simple relationship test.

Answer (score 1):

You are getting the error because reference column(`survey_id`) may contain a `null` or invalid reference id.

If the `null` or invalid reference is allowed then, change the code to handle it

```
( self.survey and acting_user == self.survey.contact ) or acting_user.administrator?
```

Comment: It could also be a reference to an invalid ID.

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to echo what the other two have said.  The survey you are trying to reference is `nil`, and `nil` does not have a method called `contact`.  I am going to offer up a slightly different solution:

```
def create_permitted?
  acting_user == survey.try(:contact) or acting_user.administrator?
end
```

The `#try` method exists on `nil` and on `survey`.  It basically wraps the method call in a `rescue`.  Conceptually, it looks like:

```
def try(method_name, *args)
  self.send(method_name, args) rescue nil
end
```

This may reduce the amount of code that you have to write to catch conditions where a relationship may not be present, preventing a `NoMethodError` exception.

`#try` is part of the Rails core extensions for `Object`.  In reality, it does not work as I have above, since exceptions arising from calls to `Object#try` will still happen as they normally should.  Instead, it extends `Object` by calling `send`.  It extends `NilClass` by returning `nil`, so it does not try to send any method to `NilClass`, preventing a `NoMethodError`.  As tadman points out in the comments, a catch-all exception handler is normally not a good idea.

https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/6ef9fda1a39f45e2d18aba4881f60a19589a2c77/activesupport/lib/active_support/core_ext/object/try.rb

**Update**

A better solution, and one that I forgot about, is to use `delegate`.

For example:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  delegate :contact, to: :survey, prefix: true, allow_nil: true
end
```

Then you would call `user.survey_contact`, and would fail gracefully if the survey is `nil`.

Comment: Nice, the `try` method absolutely fits here.

Comment: Writing a so-called [Pokemon Exception Handler](http://www.dodgycoder.net/2011/11/yoda-conditions-pokemon-exception.html) with `rescue nil` is a really bad idea and is a terrible form of defensive programming. This will consume legitimate problems with calling that method and will hide errors that would be trivial to fix with a proper stack trace. If you're expecting a `NoMethodError`, rescue that and *only* that.

Comment: I'm not writing that so-called Pokemon Exception handler.  It is part of Rails.  It does not work like I described it; rather it defines try on Object and on NilClass, calling `send` on Object and returning `nil` on NilClass.  Exceptions arising from `send` will still happen.  I was only explaining conceptually how it works.  https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/6ef9fda1a39f45e2d18aba4881f60a19589a2c77/activesupport/lib/active_support/core_ext/object/try.rb.  Otherwise, I agree.  Catching exceptions should be targeted at the specific exceptions.